# Is there an Arch derivative for Raspberry Pi 2 that has desktop environment preinstalled?

Tags: pi-2, archlinux, operating-systems

I have a Raspberry Pi 2B, and want to install an Arch based distro on it. Is there a derivative of Arch that supports Pi 2B and also comes with desktop environment preinstalled?

Arch Linux Arm Supports Pi 2, but does not have desktop preinstalled (following the Arch philosophy).
Manjaro has desktop preinstalled, but it does not support Pi 2 anymore.

Comment: [Arch Linux ARM](https://archlinuxarm.org) carries forward the Arch Linux philosophy of simplicity and user-centrism, targeting and accommodating **competent Linux users** by giving them **complete control and responsibility** over the system. Instructions are provided to assist in navigating the nuances of installation on the various ARM platforms; however, the system itself will offer little assistance to the user.

Comment: @Milliways I know that. I am looking for an Arch derivative that offers GUI out of the box (some Arch derivatives indeed do so), and also supports Pi2